# How to enable Free Lambda/DynamoDB Caching

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, serverless

**Problem Description**

I created a simple REST API using AWS Lambda and I'm saving the data in AWS DynamoDB (all using Serverless framework). The latter is defined as `PAY_PER_REQUEST`. Currently, the API is not very much used, however when the app scales, it can induce significant additional costs.

**What I have tried**

I came to the conclusion that there are two options:

1. either I cache the DB values
2. or I cache the API Gateway response

Although paid, I have tried the AWS DynamoDB DAX but it's a paid feature and I'm looking for an alternative (with code) to minimize requests to the Database when it comes to `GET` requests that are unlikely to change within 24 hours.

I also made some research and found out that it's possible to enable caching in API Gateway, but I'm not sure what's the best/cost-effective method of doing this. Maybe someone has a practical example that explains how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am being using [AWS Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/)(in my case scenario a memcached) to cache all the hits to the database. From a code point of view, it was very easy to extend the REST API to check in the cache and if is not there, go to the database, add the result to the cache and return.

That was very cost effective and very easy to implement on the lambda.

The other alternative is to enable caching for a specified stage at the [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/). 
When you enable caching, you must choose a cache capacity. In general, a larger capacity gives a better performance, but also costs more. By default only GET methods are cached.

I suggest you to check your use case and select the most cost effective solution based on your current loads.